# How to create lists from objects

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have an inventory program which reads lists from an excel file and then creates a class. I want to override new values of objects in the list then I will export the list to excel. Here I import the lists from the excel file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('stock.xlsx')

inventory_code = df['code'].tolist()
inventory_name= df['name'].tolist()
inventory_amount = df['amount'].tolist()
inventory_unit = df["birim"].tolist()
inventory_location=df["location"].tolist()
```

And then I create the class

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self,i_code,i_amount,i_unit,i_location):
        self.i_code=i_code
        self.i_amount=i_amount
        self.i_unit=i_unit
        self.i_location=i_location
    def info(self):
        print("Product code:", self.i_code, "Amount:", self.i_amount, "Unit:", self.i_unit, "Place:", self.i_location)
    def add(self, add_amount):
        self.i_amount += add_amount
    def update(self):
        mylist2.append(self.i_amount)
        

for i in range(0,len(inventory_name)):
    globals()[inventory_name[i]]=Inventory(inventory_code[i],inventory_amount[i],inventory_unit[i],inventory_location[i])
```

Now, I want to create a new list, mylist2 which contains inventory amount as before and the new value of folyo.

```
mylist2=[]
folyo.info()
folyo.add(999999)
folyo.update()
folyo.info()

print(mylist2)
```

In this code, here is the output:

```
Product code: 0 Amount: 500 Unit: m2 Place: storage_1
Product code: 0 Amount: 1000499 Unit: m2 Place: storage_1
[1000499]
```

However, my update command saves only the mentioned thing, in this case amount folyo. I want to save all objects. How can I solve this?

I think that updating only the relevant thing can be a solution. However,  my solution gives only an empty list.

```
    def update(self):
        for i in range(0, len(mylist2)):
            if inventory_code[i] == self.i_code:
                mylist2[i]= self.i_amount
            else:
                pass
```

Thank you!

Solved as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('stock.xlsx')

inventory_code = df['code'].tolist()
inventory_name= df['name'].tolist()
inventory_amount = df['amount'].tolist()
inventory_unit = df["birim"].tolist()
inventory_location=df["location"].tolist()

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self,i_code,i_amount,i_unit,i_location):
        self.i_code=i_code
        self.i_amount=i_amount
        self.i_unit=i_unit
        self.i_location=i_location

    def info(self):
        print("Product code:", self.i_code, "Amount:", self.i_amount, "Unit:", self.i_unit, "Place:", self.i_location)

    def add(self, add_amount):
        self.i_amount += add_amount



    def update(self):
        for i in range(0, len(inventory_name)):
            if inventory_code[i] == self.i_code:
                mylist2.append(self.i_amount)
            else:
                mylist2.append(inventory_amount[i])



for i in range(0,len(inventory_name)):
    globals()[inventory_name[i]]=Inventory(inventory_code[i],inventory_amount[i],inventory_unit[i],inventory_location[i])


mylist2=[]
folyo.info()
folyo.add(4000)
folyo.update()
folyo.info()

print(mylist2)

print(len(inventory_amount))
print(len(mylist2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add folyo to your list,
Either initialise the list with an Inventory object

```
mylist2 = [Inventory ()]
# access the object by this code below
mylist2[0].info()
```

Or
After you are done with updating folyo

```
mylist2.append(folyo)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Let me clarify my question. I want to update the amount of folyo in inventory list rather than creating an unordered list since I want to export it to excel.

Comment: Do you mean the globals variable ? Which has all the inventory objects

Comment: Yes. I want to have inventory_amount as a list which contains all stock at the end of the day.